# Asking general questions

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I was thinking about asking some general questions, and potentially also flag them to be CW. Do you think they would be okay to post on the site, or they'd still be off-topic:

I'm thinking about questions like:

- What do you think one should do in the first months after moving to another country?
- How to handle cultural differences with your neighbours / coworkers?
- What are the usual things you have to do in your home country before moving away?

etc.

Answer (score 4):

You should not consider community wiki for *anything* other than a canonical post that needs to be editable by a broader group of users. Don't use it to dodge rep gains or losses, and it doesn't magically cure intrinsic problems with questions.

Of your list, I found *this* to be the most on-topic:

> How to handle cultural differences with your neighbours / coworkers?

And that [was asked](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/255/how-do-i-deal-with-cultural-differences) with mixed reception. Despite leaving what I thought was a very objective and reasonably comprehensive answer, it was placed on-hold as too broad.

I don't think asking for a strategy to not make a moron out of yourself in a strange culture is too broad, I think it rather illustrates the scope and complexity of *real* problems that we face day to day.

The third question could be good, and I think useful because transplanting your life to another continent is an *extraordinarily* complicated process. What documents do you need to make sure you have and bring? What medical considerations do you need to consider? What do you need put in place to manage any lingering affairs state side? How are you going to supply yourself with money if you need it? I think that could be a canonical post.

Just don't seed content for the sake of seeding content. We've got over 100 open *very* well scoped and written questions, we don't need to worry about coming up with more just for the sake of having them. A little broad is okay if the problem *itself* is a tad overwhelming and there can be a limited number of well scoped answers.

As long as you keep it to problems you are facing, or *have* faced and overcome, then I think we're in good shape.

Answer (score 3):

The first question is completely unclear, or too broad. A valid answer is: *If you came to get a job, get a job.* But that's probably not what you had in mind.

For the cultural differences, if you travel to country X, you don't need to do anything at all because the country is very cosmopolitan and open-minded, and if you travel to country Y, you better study a lot of the local customs, because you can easily be fined, jailed or stoned if you don't. This makes it simply too broad. Such question would be fine if more localized, for example: *I like to wear a pink full-body lycra suit for everyday running. Should I change my habit when coming to Quebec?* However, even such question is ... strange.

For the third question, I think you can find a reasonable universal answer, but I'm not sure that you can cover most of the cases well. In some countries, you have to unregister from health insurance and in some you do not. In some of them, you don't have any bank fees so it makes sense to keep your bank account, etc.